# Edit BGP on IOS XE3

Tags: bgp, ios-xe, asr

i need to edit my BGP Running , and add more Neighbor

but when try this

```
FiberISP-Cisco(config)#router bgp 203725
BGP is already running; AS is 203735
FiberISP-Cisco(config)#
```

how to edit and add more Neighbor with our stop BGP ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`router bgp 203725` specifies *your* local AS-number, not the peer AS-number. A router can be part of only one ASN.

It seems that you're just making a typo though: `203725` and `203735` are two different numbers. So you can configure more peers by starting with `router bgp 203735` (unless your entire BGP config is wrong, and your ASN is actually 203725).

Comment: thanks for try helping , bro the BGP now is working fine , but i just need to add more neighbor

Comment: What is your AS-number? You are either making a typo (203725 vs 203735) or you're misunderstading what `router bgp` does.

Comment: hahaha , thanks for help, this my fault , i was write wrong ASN